# Add shell (bash/zsh) tab completion to custom command by running existing completion with arguments

Tags: bash, zsh, tab-completion

In our code base we have a few convenience executables that are automatically loaded to the environment for anyone cloning the code (using [direnv](https://direnv.net/)).

This is a general question, but for the purpose of this question let's use `kubectl` as an example.

We have this executable file named `kl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  

STACK="$1"
exec kubectl --context=our_cluster_name --namespace="$STACK" "$@"
```

Then we have variations for the prod, staging and dev namespaces (`klp`, `kls` and `kld` respectively) e.g. `kls`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec kl staging "$@"
```

`kubectl` has fantastic auto-completion, but if we use any of the `kl` variations, we don't get auto complete. I've done a lot of searches here and couldn't find how I can utilize an existing completion function to implement new completions.

I ran:

```
$ complete | grep kubectl
```

and got

```
complete -o default -F __start_kubectl kubectl
complete -F _minimal __start_kubectl
```

Basically what I want is a new entry there so that `kl[d|s|p]` will be completed with `__start_kubectl` but as if it already has the `--context` and `--namespace` arguments populated.

Ideally we'd want a solution that works for both Bash and Zsh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Zsh, instead of using executable files, if you just define `klp`, `kls` and `kld` as aliases and you make sure the `COMPLETE_ALIASES` option is **unset**, (Oh, the irony!) then Zsh will internally substitute the alias when offering completions and it will work just fine.

Comment: They're not aliases. `kls` for example is defined as `exec kl staging "$@"` in an executable, `kl` is another executable that uses the arguments from `kls` and adds `--namespace=staging` at the end. (I'd paste it but comments don't have good code blocks)

Comment: Could you convert them to aliases? That would solve the problem.